# How to implement Iterator before and after method with double linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, doubly-linked-list

I have my doubly linked list class and I can implement its
Iterator& before(const Iterator& p)
and
Iterator& after(const Iterator& p)
methods but other classes(iterator, node) are implemented. How should I code these methods, any help will be appreciated

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        Elem elem;
        friend class Linkedlist;
        Node(): next(NULL), prev(NULL)
        {}
        Node(Elem elem) : elem(elem)
        {}
};
class Linkedlist { 
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        int N;

    public:

        Iterator& before(const Iterator& p);
        Iterator& after(const Iterator& p); 
class Iterator {
    private:
        Node *iter;
        //Iterator(Node* curr);         
    public:
        friend class Linkedlist; 
//rest of the methods
```

Comment: You probably want to start with adding `begin()` and `end()` members to Linkedlist

Answer (score 0):

We need to take care of certain cases in mind before implementing `before` and `after` method. Like  what if  someone passed iterator of `head` as argument to `before` method.
Then we may have to return a local iterator with null pointer but returning a local with `l-value` reference is really a problem and same problem for `after` method if we pass iterator of `tail` as argument.
So instead of having `before` and `after` please try to have `begin` and `end` method with increment/decrement operator overload for traversing.
See interface of `std::vector` , `std::list` etc.

Comment: I do have them( begin and end), if i have them, how should I solve this problem?